# Git console in Netbeans

Tags: git, netbeans, console, netbeans-8

I've just installed Netbeans 8 and I'd like to start using Git. There are plenty of buttons, menus, etc. but where can I find Git console?
I use Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably best off installing it directly if you want the console; the IDEs will often only give the menu integrated options.

Git's website has the console version for Windows: http://git-scm.com/

Answer (score 1):

To make terminal work in your Netbeans IDE you just need to install cygwin. While you installing/setting up cygwin you have to select packages to install. Type "git" in search input, while selecting packages, to find all git packages. All git packages are sorted by categories. You don't need all of them. To make git work in your terminal choose category "devel" and "git: Distributed version control system". Finish setup by clicking on "next" button.
Now restart your NetBeans IDE and use git in your terminal.
[image: terminal with git]