# Error when trying to change branch (Git and Netbeans)

Tags: java, git, netbeans

I have a Netbeans project with a local Git repository on Windows containing several branches. 
When I try to leave the active branch and switch to another one I get an error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\myFolder._myClass.java343227714550314005.tmp (Access denied)

Trying to switch to other branches does not help either: error about the same or some other file.
Tried to commit and change again: same problem. The file might have been open in Netbeans, but is closed now. 
Every time I try to switch, more source files disappear. 
Tried to reset the active branch, but get a similar error.

Any ideas how to repair? Don't want to lose all the history!!

Comment: Is that file currently open (in NetBeans or otherwise)?

Comment: May have been open in Netbeans the first time as it was the file with the last commited changes, but that was never a problem before

Comment: Do you have any uncommitted changes? What is the output of `git status` from the command line? Do you get the same error when switching branches from the command line? (`git checkout <newbranch>`)

Comment: BTW, please [edit] your post to add any additional information about your issue. That way it will be easier for other users to find without digging through the comments.

Comment: Good point, updated the question to contain the new points.

Comment: I accessed Git only from the Netbeans menu so far, dont know wether its possible or how to do it via command line.

Comment: Have you tried to do a `git reset` on your currently active branch?

Comment: If you are on Windows, try searching your programs for Git Bash. Otherwise, just open a terminal. To switch branches from the command line, do `git checkout <branchname>`.

Comment: There is no Git Bash in my programs. The command line does not recognize 'git' command. I think there might not be such option as I did not install Git separetely (only within Netbeans). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22674978/git-console-in-netbeans.

Comment: Reset (hard) results in ' ava.io.FileNotFoundException: 
H:\myFolder\._build.xml2355639488917397328.tmp (Access denied)'